# Delphi ZLib Compress / Decompress

Tags: delphi, zlib, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've got a minor issue with decompressing using the ZLib unit in Delphi

```
unit uZCompression;

interface

uses
  uCompression;

type
  TZZipCompression = class(TInterfacedObject, ICompression)
  public
    function DoCompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
    function DoDecompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
    function GetWindowsBits: Integer; virtual;
  end;

  TZGZipCompression = class(TZZipCompression)
    function GetWindowsBits: Integer; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.ZLib, System.Classes, uMxKxUtils;

{ TZCompression }

function TZZipCompression.DoCompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
var
  LContentStream, LOutputStream: TMemoryStream;
  LCompressedStream: TZCompressionStream;
begin
  LContentStream := ByteArrayToStream(aContent);

  LOutputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  LCompressedStream := TZCompressionStream.Create(LOutputStream, zcDefault, GetWindowsBits);
  LCompressedStream.CopyFrom(LContentStream, LContentStream.Size);
  LCompressedStream.Free;

  Result := StreamToByteArray(LOutputStream);

  LOutputStream.Free;
  LContentStream.Free;
end;

function TZZipCompression.DoDecompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
var
  LContentStream, LOutputStream: TMemoryStream;
  LDecompressedStream: TZDecompressionStream;
begin
  LContentStream := ByteArrayToStream(aContent);

  LOutputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  LDecompressedStream := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LContentStream);
  LOutputStream.CopyFrom(LDecompressedStream, LDecompressedStream.Size);
  LDecompressedStream.Free;

  Result := StreamToByteArray(LOutputStream);

  LOutputStream.Free;
  LContentStream.Free;
end;

function TZZipCompression.GetWindowsBits: Integer;
begin
  Result := 15;
end;

{ TZGZipCompression }

function TZGZipCompression.GetWindowsBits: Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited;
  Result := Result + 16;
end;

end.
```

This is my unit which is driven by an interface (which you don't need to know about), and data is passed in and out through a TArray variables.

I've coded it to be able to do 2 types of compression, standard zip and gzip which is determined by the windowsbits passed in to the functions.

Here are a couple of other functions being used to convert the TArray to TMemoryStream

```
function ByteArrayToStream(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Result.Write(aContent, length(aContent)*SizeOf(aContent[0]));
  Result.Position := 0;
end;

function StreamToByteArray(aStream: TMemoryStream): TArray<Byte>;
var
  LStreamPos: Int64;
begin
  if Assigned(aStream) then
  begin
    LStreamPos := aStream.Position;
    aStream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(Result, aStream.Size);
    aStream.Read(Result, aStream.Size);
    aStream.Position := LStreamPos;
  end
  else
    SetLength(Result, 0);
end;
```

Now I can compress and decompress to .zip using the TZZipCompression class perfectly fine (it doesn't open up as a zip file, but it does decompress back to the original file which I can open and edit).

I can also compress to .gz using the TZGZipCompression class fine as well (interestingly I can open this gzip file perfectly well).

My issue however is that it won't decompress back from the .gz file and throws and error as soon as it hits

```
LOutputStream.CopyFrom(LDecompressedStream, LDecompressedStream.Size)
```

Funnily enough the Help file example has it as below

```
LOutputStream.CopyFrom(LDecompressedStream, 0)
```

But this doesn't work either.

Can anyone spot the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conversion functions between `TArray<Byte>` and `TMemoryStream` are wrong, as you are not accessing the array content correctly.  `TArray` is a dynamic array.  When calling `TMemoryStream.Write()` and `TMemoryStream.Read()`, you are passing the memory address of the `TArray` itself, not the memory address of the data that the `TArray` points at.  You need to reference the `TArray` to get the correct memory address, eg:

```
function ByteArrayToStream(const aContent: TArray<Byte>): TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if Length(aContent) > 0 then
      Result.WriteBuffer(aContent[0], Length(aContent));
    Result.Position := 0;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

function StreamToByteArray(aStream: TMemoryStream): TArray<Byte>;
begin
  if Assigned(aStream) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, aStream.Size);
    if Length(Result) > 0 then
      Move(aStream.Memory^, Result[0], aStream.Size);
  end
  else
    SetLength(Result, 0);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function ByteArrayToStream(const aContent: TArray<Byte>): TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Result.WriteBuffer(PByte(aContent)^, Length(aContent));
    Result.Position := 0;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

function StreamToByteArray(aStream: TMemoryStream): TArray<Byte>;
begin
  if Assigned(aStream) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, aStream.Size);
    Move(aStream.Memory^, PByte(Result)^, aStream.Size);
  end
  else
    SetLength(Result, 0);
end;
```

That being said, you don't need to waste memory making copies of the array data using `TMemoryStream`.  You can use `TBytesStream` instead (since dynamic arrays are reference counted), eg:

```
function TZZipCompression.DoCompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
var
  LContentStream, LOutputStream: TBytesStream;
  LCompressedStream: TZCompressionStream;
begin
  LContentStream := TBytesStream.Create(aContent);
  try
    LOutputStream := TBytesStream.Create(nil);
    try    
      LCompressedStream := TZCompressionStream.Create(LOutputStream, zcDefault, GetWindowsBits);
      try
        LCompressedStream.CopyFrom(LContentStream, 0);
      finally
        LCompressedStream.Free;
      end;
      Result := Copy(LOutputStream.Bytes, 0, LOutputStream.Size);
    finally
      LOutputStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LContentStream.Free;
  end;
end;

function TZZipCompression.DoDecompression(aContent: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
var
  LContentStream, LOutputStream: TBytesStream;
  LDecompressedStream: TZDecompressionStream;
begin
  LContentStream := TBytesStream.Create(aContent);
  try    
    LOutputStream := TBytesStream.Create(nil);
    try
      LDecompressedStream := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LContentStream, GetWindowsBits);
      try
        LOutputStream.CopyFrom(LDecompressedStream, 0);
      finally
        LDecompressedStream.Free;
      end;
      Result := Copy(LOutputStream.Bytes, 0, LOutputStream.Size);
    finally
      LOutputStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LContentStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Remy.
I do however get the same results I got last time.
I can compress the file to zip ok (but not open it as a zip file), and decompress the file back to the original and open ok.
I can compress the file to gz ok, and open the file to see the file inside, but it won't decompress. Just keeps giving the error "Data error" when calling
    LOutputStream.CopyFrom(LDecompressedStream, 0);

Comment: On a side note it looks like capacity is a protected property now in my version of Delphi so I just replaced the last bit to not check for capacity and do this all the time Copy(LOutputStream.Bytes, 0, LOutputStream.Size)

Comment: I worked it out, I forgot to add the WindowsBits to the decompression create stream. It didn't know it was meant to be doing gz decompression and defaults back to zip.

Comment: LDecompressedStream := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LContentStream, GetWindowsBits);

Comment: @mikelittlewood thanks. I have updated the code in my answer